# Website taking too much time to load on browser

Tags: wordpress, page-load-time, slowdown, load-time

my website is running slow https://www.creekharbour.co/
too much server response time. FPC is also very high I have installed the LiteSpeed cache plugin. it decreases the load time but my contact form 7 stopped working. then I have to deactivate that plugin. Can anybody tell me an easy solution as I am not a developer :(

Comment: You may want to consider hiring a developer for this. Optimizing a website requires knowing what to tweak and how. Stackoverflow is a site to discuss programming questions, not to provide tech support.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend linking your website with https://www.cloudflare.com/
Just follow instructions

Comment: yes i have already linked that before but still i am facing load time issues

Comment: I went through your site on gtmetrix full site takes 20sec+ if your running contact form 7 try disabling it and check load time... maybe your contact form 7 is slowing down the site.

Comment: Check this image : https://prnt.sc/10z2a2j your site waterfall shows contact form 7 is taking time to load.

Comment: Thanks, brother for your support